# Counting filtered rows in Scala Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have Spark process that performs several filters on a dataframe:

```scala
df.filter([filter1])
.filter([filter2])
.filter([filter3])
...
```

I want to count how many rows were filtered out with each filter.

i.e. in the end I would like to have the information:

```
filteredByFilter1: 6
filteredByFilter2: 61
filteredByFilter3: 42
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753345/counting-filtered-items-on-dataframe-spark) thread on how to achieve this with RDDs. My question is is it possible to implement this without converting to RDD and back.

Also, there is a problem with the implementation I linked as to my understanding if spark has to rerun a task it will not reset the accumulator's value for that task and so the result value will be bigger than the amount of filtered data. I would like to know if it is possible to overcome this.

In addition the solution has to have minimal performance impact, as this is a high volume pipeline which we can't afford to increase the load on too much.

thanks

Comment: You can use `Dataframe.transform` and run the `filter` in each defined transformation along with a `count` call on each intermediate dataframe. That will trigger an action on each filter though and you may lose any benefits of filter push-down. For the issue with accumulators in transformations, I don't think it can be overcome since they can be rerun due to task or stage failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @m_vemuri pointed out in the comments, there will be some performance impacts to keeping track of what it filtered out.

After some experimentation the best method I can think of is to start off with tracking which values meet your filtering conditions, and then filter these out at the end (**without having to re-run your filters**).

This isn't as elegant as calling `.filter([filter1]).filter([filter2]).filter([filter3])` as in your Question, but is the most concise I can conceive.

## TL;DR

```scala
val df = (1 to 100).toDF("n")

def firstFilter  = col("n") % 2 === 0
def secondFilter = col("n") % 4 === 0
def thirdFilter  = col("n") % 8 === 0

val filteredDF = df
    .withColumn("firstFilter", firstFilter)
    .withColumn("secondFilter", secondFilter)
    .withColumn("thirdFilter", thirdFilter)

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def countFilter(df: DataFrame, c: String): DataFrame = 
    df.filter(col(c) === false)
        .groupBy(col(c))
        .agg(count(c).as(s"filterCount"))
        .withColumn("filter", lit(c))
        .select("filter", "filterCount")

def countFilters(df: DataFrame, cs: String*): DataFrame = 
    cs.tail
        .foldLeft(countFilter(df, cs.head))(
            (acc, c) => acc.union(countFilter(df, c))
        )

// produces a DataFrame with a count, per filter, of the rows removed
countFilters(filteredDF, "firstFilter", "secondFilter", "thirdFilter")
    .show()

filteredDF
    .filter(col("firstFilter") &&
           col("secondFilter") &&
           col("thirdFilter"))
    .select("n")
    .show(5)
```

gives:

```
+------------+-----------+
|      filter|filterCount|
+------------+-----------+
| firstFilter|         50|
|secondFilter|         75|
| thirdFilter|         88|
+------------+-----------+

+---+
|  n|
+---+
|  8|
| 16|
| 24|
| 32|
| 40|
+---+
only showing top 5 rows
```

## Full solution

Starting with some example data:

```scala
val df = (1 to 100).toDF("n")

df.show(5)
```

gives:

```
+---+
|  n|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
+---+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Then with three filters we create three new columns, tracking the results against each filter (you could alternatively only have one of these columns, by overwriting it each time, combining the results):

```scala
def firstFilter  = col("n") % 2 === 0
def secondFilter = col("n") % 4 === 0
def thirdFilter  = col("n") % 8 === 0

val filteredDF = df
    .withColumn("firstFilter", firstFilter)
    .withColumn("secondFilter", secondFilter)
    .withColumn("thirdFilter", thirdFilter)

filteredDF.show(8)
```

gives:

```
+---+-----------+------------+-----------+
|  n|firstFilter|secondFilter|thirdFilter|
+---+-----------+------------+-----------+
|  1|      false|       false|      false|
|  2|       true|       false|      false|
|  3|      false|       false|      false|
|  4|       true|        true|      false|
|  5|      false|       false|      false|
|  6|       true|       false|      false|
|  7|      false|       false|      false|
|  8|       true|        true|       true|
+---+-----------+------------+-----------+
only showing top 8 rows
```

At this point we still have all of the original rows, however we have already run each filter, storing the results in new columns with `true`/`false` values.

Now we can count the number of rows that did not match each condition:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def countFilter(df: DataFrame, c: String): DataFrame = 
    df.filter(col(c) === false)
        .groupBy(col(c))
        .agg(count(c).as(s"filterCount"))
        .withColumn("filter", lit(c))
        .select("filter", "filterCount")

def countFilters(df: DataFrame, cs: String*): DataFrame = 
    cs.tail
        .foldLeft(countFilter(df, cs.head))(
            (acc, c) => acc.union(countFilter(df, c))
        )

// produces a DataFrame with a count, per filter, of the rows removed
countFilters(filteredDF, "firstFilter", "secondFilter", "thirdFilter")
    .show()
```

gives:

```
+------------+-----------+
|      filter|filterCount|
+------------+-----------+
| firstFilter|         50|
|secondFilter|         75|
| thirdFilter|         88|
+------------+-----------+
```

and we can apply the filtering:

```scala
filteredDF
    .filter(col("firstFilter") &&
           col("secondFilter") &&
           col("thirdFilter"))
    .select("n")
    .show(5)
```

gives:

```
+---+
|  n|
+---+
|  8|
| 16|
| 24|
| 32|
| 40|
+---+
only showing top 5 rows
```

## Discussion

> Won't this impact performance pretty severely to add a count for each filter? Especially for a high volume pipeline

The counts being performed are on boolean columns, and only counting the `false` values at that. Even for a large Dataset these counts should scale, and perform, well.

There naturally will be some overhead when tracking the number of rows filtered, which is something Spark doesn't expose out of the box.

> What if I create a custom set accumulator and add to it the row IDs in the transformation (like in the answer I linked), then get the set size in the driver?

The answer you linked is a way of solving the problem, yes; this involves using RDD and custom functions however. My solution uses the built in Spark functions which can be better optimized.

I would recommend running both against your dataset, if possible, and compare the results.

> ..won't this solve spark's re running of transformations problem?

I don't see a re-running problem here, as my solution doesn't repeat anything, instead splitting the filtering process into two steps:

1. Calculate a `true`/`false` value as to whether each row satisfies each filter. (Can be fully parallelised)
2. Aggregate the counts of `false` values per filter.
3. Perform each filter without rerunning the filter logic (using the `true`/`false` values already calculated. (Can be fully parallelised)

Comment: 1. I don't understand the added value of including the value of the previous filter in the current filter.
2. I may have not been clear enough. I want to count how much values were filtered for each different filter. I added more info to the question.
3. Won't this impact performance pretty severely to add a count for each filter? Especially for a high volume pipeline

Comment: What if I create a custom set accumulator and add to it the row IDs in the transformation (like in the answer I linked), then get the set size in the driver? Assuming the set is small enough, won't this solve spark's re running of transformations problem?

Comment: Hi. I can update my answer to include how to have a count per filter. Since the filtering logic has been performed already and the result stored in a boolean column, performing the counts will scale well (it's easy to count `true`/`false` even for large datasets).

Comment: The answer you linked is a way of solving the problem, yes; this involves using RDD and custom functions however. My solution uses the built in Spark functions which can be better optimized.

Comment: In the end I went for the solution you provided. The problem with the accumulator solution is that it doesn't reset a task fails and is then rerun which will then provide incorrect results.